# What is wrong with my gravity calculation?

Tags: java, physics, physics-engine

Im trying to create a method to calculate the fall time for an object using real formulas. Well I came up with this:

```
    public static double calculate_fall_time(float height) {
        final float GRAVITY = 9.81f;
        float h = (1/2)*GRAVITY*2;
        float h2 = GRAVITY/GRAVITY;
        double t = Math.sqrt(((2*h2)/GRAVITY));

        return t;
    }
```

Well I used to this [website](https://www.angio.net/personal/climb/speed.html) to compare the results but it wasn't the same. If I have 370 at the input then my program shows 0.4515 but the website is showing around 8,6 seconds.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem? Thanks in advance :D

**NOTE:** I know that arcade physics are much more fun but my goal is to create a rather realistic game. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Where do you use your `height` parameter inside your function?

Comment: Wait a second... thanks. I will try adding it :D

Comment: This is my new function: ``double t = Math.sqrt(2 * GRAVITY * height);`` It outputs something which looks similar to the value of the website (85.20211494220669) but it itsn't correct. (8.69)

Comment: ...why are you multiplying by gravity? Higher gravity should decrease your fall time, not increase it. How did you derive this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very simple solution to my problem. This is my code: `double t = Math.sqrt(2 * height / GRAVITY);` Thanks a lot! (ᴵᵐ ᵃⁿ ᶦᵈᶦᵒᵗ)